# SQL only different Column Data

Tags: sql, database

My db gives me following data

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
data1 data2 1    data3
data1 data2 1    data3
data1 data2 2    data3
data1 data2 2    data3
data1 data2 2    data3
```

I want following result. Only different in Col3

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
data1 data2 1    data3
data1 data2 2    data3
```

Comment: you should take a look : [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should explain what query are you using, what are you trying to get, thins tried etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the `distinct` modifier does:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM   my_table
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/063ea/2/0) to show the result.

Comment: Only different in Col3. Not @ all

Comment: @ReneB I don't understand your comment. Pleae elaborate?

Comment: DISTINCT does not help ;) same number of hits.

Comment: @ReneB check out the SQLFidlle I attached

Answer (score 0):

Group by should yield the [result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/063ea/3) you are looking for (assuming you use MS SQL):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Comment: i have +20 cols. Is that really necessary ? Want to archive that without using group by ...

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want. based on your question I would use group by, yes. If you added details and elaborated your question, maybe other solutions would be better. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The select you want to perform is actually not possible. You either provide a grouping function (sum, ave, min, max, distinct...) for all the other columns or you select all rows.

```
select MAX(col1), MAX(col2), col3, MAX(col4)
FROM myTable
group by col3;
```

Comment: You can't sum text. :) Use MAX or MIN instead.

Comment: that is of course true. I was actually thinking MIN. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are searching for this(assuming from your comment)::

```
     SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2,A.Col3,COL4 FROM TEST_TABLE CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT COL3 FROM Test_table) A
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM mytable GROUP BY col3
```